# How can I view an R32G32B32 texture?

Tags: textures, directx11, gpu, floating-point

I have a texture with `R32G32B32` floats.  I create this texture in-program on D3D11, using `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT`. Now I need to *see* the texture data for debug purposes, but it will not save to [anything but dds](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/563620-d3dx10savetexturetofile/), showing the error in debug output, "Can't find matching WIC format, please save this file to a DDS".

So, I write it to DDS but I can't open it now!  The DirectX texture tool says "An error occurred trying to open that file".

I know the texture is working because I can read it in the GPU and the colors seem correct.

How can I view an `R32G32B32` texture in an image viewer?

Comment: There is a nice [DDS viewer here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090306070943/http://www.amnoid.de/ddsview/download.html).  It doesn't seem to be able to open the texture!

Comment: I believe this should be possible with the [OpenEXR viewers](http://www.openexr.com/downloads.html), have you tried it? [Direct link](http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/openexr/openexr_viewers-1.0.2.tar.gz)

Comment: I may be being a little dense but why can you not get the contents of the texture (by mapping it, or copying to staging resource), then bit-bang the raw content into a block of memory, process the pixels from R32R32R32 into U8U8U8 then just use that block as the source for a bitmap then view and save this?

Comment: Legacy D3DX10/11 is using WIC to save most file formats, and there are basically no WIC codecs that natively support 96bpp float. The one exception is that WIC can *load* 96bpp float TIFF files, but not write them, and there are a number of bugs doing it prior to Windows 8. Legacy D3DX10/11 is going to to use the 'DX10' header extension to write out a DDS file if given the 96bbp float format. A better solution is to write it using Radiance RGBE (HDR) format which is supported by legacy D3DX9 and DirectXTex, but not D3DX10/D3DX11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could find to view a 96 bpp texture was using [NVIDIA's DDS plug-in](http://3dg.me/3d-graphics/nvidia-plug-ins-for-adobe-photoshop-x64-64bit) [direct download 64-bit](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/tools/texturetools/Photoshop_Plugins_x64_8.50.1130.1235.exe), [32-bit](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/tools/texturetools/Photoshop_Plugins_8.51.0301.0345.exe).

It's important to use the right bitness of the plug in, otherwise it won't work (which is what I found before)

Answer (score 4):

How about [using PIX for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/manders/a-painless-introduction-to-pix-for-windows)? That's probably the easiest way to view your texture.

As a bonus, you can right click your texture and "Save Picture As..." to shelve it for later, if that's something you need as well (though I'm not sure this will handle a R32G32B32 format).

Answer (score 4):

The DDS file format changed between dx9 and dx10. dx9 had been supporting a lot of new features via kludges, these new features were finally added as full types with the switch to DXGI. What this means is that most existing DDS viewers do not support any of the new texture formats or even files saved from [DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex). (The new semi-open source microsoft library for manipulating DDS files. )

DirectXTex has a command line tool called DDsView.exe that can view all file formats.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell the old DX texture tool doesn't support this format - it's certainly not available in the list of formats to convert to.  What *is* available, however, is R32G32B32A32 float, and I've tested a little and determined that it can indeed convert to, save as, and subsequently re-open using it, so you could try converting to that format before saving.

Comment: You say "the old", is there a new DX texture tool around that I should be using? I see [a bunch here](http://cs.elderscrolls.com/index.php/DDS_Tools)

Comment: None that I'm aware of - I just said "the old" because it is old!  Sorry for the confusion/false hope there.  Interesting that I tested it with the 64-bit version in the June 2010 SDK but apparently MS never updated it to support the new formats.